# preference relation.

Tags: relations, economics, utility

In the exercise below I need to check  whether the relation below is a preference relation ( need to be transitive (if $x>y$ and $y>z$ then $x>z$) and connected ). But I cannot find an example of why it would not be transitive.

$$
f\succeq g \hspace{0.5cm}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{0.5cm} f(q) \geq g(q) \hspace{1cm} \textit{ and }\hspace{1cm} q\in Q\cap[0,1] 
$$

If this $\succeq$ is transitive and connected then how I can find an utility function that represents it?

Addition: 
Sorry i mean $ \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$
Ok: so in other example i proved that the relation is not transitive, so it cannot be preference. I had 
$$
f\succeq g \hspace{0.5cm}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{0.5cm} \int_{0}^{1} f \geq \int_{1}^{2}g 
$$
I took as a $f(x)= x$, $g(x)=-x+2$, $h(x)=1$.

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} x dx= [\frac{1}{2}x]_{0}^{1} =\frac{1}{2} $$
$$ \int_{1}^{2}g(x) = \int_{1}^{2}( -x+2 )dx= -[\frac{1}{2}x^{2}]_{1}^{2} + 2[x]_{1}^{2} = -\frac{3}{2} + 2 = \frac{1}{2} $$

so it is true for $$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \geq  \int_{1}^{2}g(x) $$
now

$$ \int_{0}^{1} g(x)= \int_{0}^{1} (-x+2)dx = -[\frac{1}{2}x^{2}]_{0}^{1} + 2[x]_{0}^{1}= -\frac{1}{2} +2= \frac{3}{2} $$
$$ \int_{1}^{2}h(x) = \int_{1}^{2} 1dx = 1 $$

it is true for $$   \int_{0}^{1} g(x) \geq  \int_{1}^{2}h(x) $$
but it is not true for  $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \geq  \int_{1}^{2}h(x), (\frac{1}{2} \not \geq 1) $$

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you. (So, if you cannot find a counter-example then have you tried to prove it?)

Comment: Also, do you mean $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$?

Comment: Also i had examples $$ (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \succeq (y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}) \Leftrightarrow x_{1} \geq y_{1} or x_{2} \geq y_{2} or x_{3} \leq y_{3} $$
This is also not preference relation because it is not transitive for points $$(5,4,2) (6,8,2) (7,8,1) $$

Comment: We had lots of examples where the relation is not transitive, so i assuming that this relation with $f(q) \geq g(q) $ is also not, but i cannot find why. Maybe it is preference, but then how to find utility function.

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$? Arbitrary function from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes it will be transitive but what about connected? Can you please write down the definition of connected?

Comment: I think this relation will not be connected because, for example: 
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{4} \textit{and } g(x)=x$$
i have $$f(\frac{1}{16}) = \frac{1}{4}, g(\frac{1}{16})= \frac{1}{16}$$
that is $f(\frac{1}{16}) \geq g(\frac{1}{16})$
but for example where $q=\frac{1}{2}$ 
that is $$ f(\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}, g(\frac{1}{2}$$ and $g(\frac{1}{2} \geq f(\frac{1}{2})$
these elements $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}, g(x)=x$ i cannot compare, so it means that the relations is not connected. 
Is it right ?